# Python, problems with global variable

Tags: python, variables, global

I declare a global variable `pos`, anyway the method `printArr()` doesn't see it. The interpreter says: `undifined variable pos`. Why? Thanks

```
import nltk


class Analyzer():

    """Implements sentiment analysis."""





    def __init__(self, positives, negatives):
        global pos
        global neg
        positives=[]
        negatives=[]
        i=0
        file = open("negative-words.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            h=file.readline()
            if h!="":
                if h[0]!=';':
                    negatives.append(h)
                    i=i+1
                    print(h)

        i=0
        file = open("positive-words.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            h=file.readline()
            if h!="":
                if h[0]!=';':
                    positives.append(h)
                    i=i+1
                    print(h)
        neg=negatives
        pos=positives


    def printArr (self, arr):
        print (pos[2])
    """Initialize Analyzer."""
```

I'll try to make it easier: The next code does not work properly, the program still prints out "0", not "5"

```
import os
import sys
global x
x=0

def func1():
    x=5
def func2():
    print (x)

func2()
```

Comment: rather than a global variable, it could be an instance variable ? with `self.pos`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason for that to be global.

Comment: `global` does not declare a new "global" variable, it's only indicates that the variable needs to be looked elsewhere. So if you want to use `global` in your code - you should define those variables first

Comment: I tried running the script and it works here. It's not advisable to use global variables though.

Comment: "undifined variable pos" is not an error message the interpreter would give, even if you spelled "undefined" correctly. Are you sure that's not an IDE message?

Comment: I'll try to make it easier:

Answer (score 0):

Python will always look for local variables first before searching in global scope.

Your func2() will always refer to global value of x as x is not defined locally.

You could try to nest the 2 functions.

Func2(func1())

That way your func1 will assign value 5 to variable x and func2 will return 5 instead of 0.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The interpreter says: too many positional arguments in function call. Right now I am aware that I did not even call func2() in order to change   the variable x. Now I did it, but all the same it prints out "0"

Comment: Ok ... I am writing the code in another answer. This one did return 5

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1():
    x = 5
    return x

def func2():
    print(func1())

#It returned 5
```

Comment: func1() will create the local variable x as defined by us to be used in func2()

Comment: Thanks, Sagar. It did work for me! Am I right if I understand a global variable as that one seen in all the scopes and always retaining the last assigned value?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. And you got it absolutely right about the global variables :)

Comment: Thanks! And, in the case of Python, in order to "update" the last assigned value of a variable, I should call all the funcions that deal with that variable. Right? Anyway, I wold like to see how the modificator "global" is used.

Comment: Yup. You can also modify global variables from within the function however thats a bad practice.